# I need to make the column values of a table case Insensitive while reading them in a Spotfire Prompt from a Oracle View

Tags: oracle, plsql, spotfire

I am loading data into Spotfire report from Oracle using view. In the Spotfire Prompt when the text value is entered, whether it is Upper,lower or mixure of both the relative column values should be displayed. Since this is done at the data base level i need some way to make the column values case insensitive. 
I know that column values can be converted to upper/lower case with upper()/lower() function but i need a way so that even a mixure of upper/lower cases will search the column values.
I found one more solution for session :

```
alter session set NLS_COMP=ANSI;

alter session set NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI;
```

After using the above code any SQL search for column will be case insensitive. but i need a solution where i can use it in the view of the column element.

Answer (score 0):

Does the inputted value need to be a prompt? It would be possible to do this using a parameter (which could be set by a document property/ input field/ configuration block).

Within the SQL for your query, you could add a where clause something like

```
upper(A1."mycolumn")=upper(?myParameter)
```

After refreshing the parameters section of the information link ‘myParameter’ will appear. The information link can then be added as an on demand table, with myParameter being set via a document property.

Comment: ok, but still your solution only makes it to be searched as uppercase, i need the column value to be filtered no matter what the case Eg . 'myColUmn' and yes and the user has to give input in prompt, that why i am trying to find solution that can be implemented in a view which i am using already